# Эффективная замена std::vector?

Tags: c++

Есть набор элементов, примерно 27 миллионов типа float. Необходимо, что бы все элементы хранились в памяти. Используется `std::vector`. С элементами из vector производятся различные операции. Доступ по индексу. 
Есть ли способ по-другому организовать хранение информации, поскольку вычислений с данными много, а обращение через `vector.at` медленное?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Используйте прямую индексацию через перегруженный оператор []. В методе vector::at есть проверки на корректность индекса - это может уменьшать производительность. Сам по себе std::vector достаточно быстр - не хуже по производительности обычного динамического массива.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло!

Comment: Пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

При хорошей реализации декартово дерево по неявному ключу (структура данных) может заменить vector.

Насколько разумнее это делать, сказать не могу, решайте сами, вот ссылка о [структуре](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/treap).

Answer (score 1):

Нашёлся метод, позволяющий ускорить вычисления. Он не связан с изменением алгоритма программы. Проведена компиляция с помощью Intel C++ Compiler с включением оптимизаций под конкретный процессор. Скорость обработки увеличилась примерно в 12 раз по сравнению с билдом без оптимизаций. Выходные данные идентичны.

Comment: По сравнению с дебаг-версией? Тогда это не фокус! :)

Answer (score -3):

Если Вы используете `std::vector<>` исключительно для доступа к элементам по индексу (через `at()`), то стоит подумать об использовании обычных ("сишных") массивов. Тогда, поскольку операции на массивами в С/С++ де-факто (да и де-юре) являются арифметикой над указателями, Вы получите именно скорость доступа `O(1)` и заметно меньшую, чем в случае с `std::vector<>.at()`.

Недостатки:

- придется вспомнить `malloc()` :-)
- а если возможно изменение размеров - то и `realloc()`
- никто за Вас не будет контролировать выход за пределы массива.

Безусловно, перегруженный `[]` в `std::vector` практически решает проблему, но вот вопрос более философский - стоит ли использовать более "сложную" структуру данных?

Успехов!

Comment: А почему бы не использовать более сложную структуру данных, если она забесплатно предоставляет нам бОльшие возможности? Хотя бы метод size() и стандартные алгоритмы.